# set HTML Attributes As Element Properties vs setAttribute method

Tags: javascript, html

my code as follow :

```
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script>
                var div = document.createElement('div');

                div.setAttribute('style','background-color: gray; border-bottom: dotted black;padding: 3px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold;');
                div .setAttribute('textcontent', 'brick2');  // not work
                //div.textContent = 'brick';              //  work          


                document.body.appendChild(brick);

            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

there are two way of set property of element,set HTML Attributes As Element Properties or setAttribute method .

when use "div.textContent = 'brick'" this code set HTML Attributes As Element Properties,the browser can display text normal,but when use "div.setAttribute('textContent', 'brick')" this code which browser can't display text?

I am confused as that,so I study property of element,reference  as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) , but element.style is similar as element.textContent . why setAttribute('style'...) is work  but
setAttribute('textContent'...) is not ?

my browser is chrome 36.0.1985.143 m

Comment: Many properties will have a one-to-one relationship with an attribute, but this is not always the case. Child content is a classic example - whilst the *appearance* of child content can be altered through attributes on the parent, I can't think of an example of an element where child (rather than replaced) content can be altered by setting attribute values. The function and properties appendChild, innerHTML and textContent will all allow you to manipulate the DOM and add child content - but none of these properties have corresponding attributes on the parent element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `textContent` is a property of the `div` element which you've just created. Setting `textContent` through `setAttribute()` will give your `div` element a new attribute:

```
<div style="..." textContent="brick"></div>
```

...which isn't a valid HTML attribute and will not do anything by itself.